# Copy files from specific SP folder every morning from client

Tags: powershell, script, register

**Context**

Using PowerShell, I was hoping to schedule a task to pull down files from specific folders on SharePoint automatically every morning. It seems fairly simple, but I cannot even manage to connect to the SharePoint. The SharePoint is located online, and I login with my Active Directory information.

I have PowerShell and have been running PowerShell ISE. I also have the SharePoint Online Management Shell and SharePoint Client Components installed.

The first code I try is:

```
$fromfile = "https://domain.com/sites/project/Shared%20Documents/folder1/folderA/test.pdf"
$tofile   = "C:\test.pdf"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$webclient.DownloadFile($fromfile, $tofile)
```

But I get a 403 forbidden error. My guess is it has something to do with my credentials. I tried another code, this time using the SharePoint shell features:

```
$fromsite = "https://domain.com/sites/project"

$fromfile = "Shared%20Documents/folder1/folderA/test.pdf"
$tofile   = "C:\test.pdf"

$web = Get-SPWeb $fromsite
$file = $web.GetFile($fromfile)
$filebytes = $file.OpenBinary()

$filestream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($tofile, "Create")
$binarywriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($filestream)
$binarywriter.write($filebytes)
$binarywriter.Close()
```

This gives me there error: *Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.*

So then I try running:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
```

But then I get *Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.* So for good measure I check the following

```
Get-PSSnapin -Registered
```

Unsurprisingly, the list is blank. This means that I need to somehow register those Snapins. This leads me to this site: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step/

I have followed everything successfully, until *Get-WSManCredSSP*. I get this response: *The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials. 
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.*. So I followed everything on here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh751273.aspx and I cannot figure out where to go from here.

**Request**

- Is there a better way to write a script to pull these files? Perhaps one that wouldn't cause any of these issues?
- If not, how can I get SharePoint functionality in PowerShell? How can I get the SharePoint snap-ins to be registered?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get it to work using PowerShell with this method. I believe it's because I am not running the commands on the SharePoint server itself.

Instead, I created a batch script with the following:

```
net use X: "\\sharepoint.site@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\project\Shared Documents\folder 1\folder 2"
robocopy "X:" %dest% /LEV:2 /s
```

(*%dest% being a variable I defined earlier*)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED` header with `f` value using following code: `$webclient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")` before executing `$webclient.DownloadFile()`.

According to `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` snap-in and `Get-SPWeb` cmdlet - they can be used only directly on SharePoint server.